# Vertical Align on button wont work

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

I want to create a menu that has buttons in it but for some reason the buttons dont get aligned at the buttom of the div. I have done this before the same way using tables and then it worked but now im trying without the tables and for some reason this does not work.

my css:

```
body 
{
    background: #bbb url(../images/Mywallpap.jpg) no-repeat;
    font-family: Sans-Serif;
    padding:0;
    margin: 0;
}

#Background
{
    width: 750px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #FEFEFE;
}

.Menu
{
    height: 60px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}

.Menu div
{
    height : 30px;
    margin-left: 25px;
    padding: 0;

}
```

My html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link href="MyCss.css" type="text/css" rel="Stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>

<div id="Background">
    <div class="Menu">
       <div>
       <button>Test</button>
       </div>
    </div>



</div>

</body>
</html>
```

what am i missing here?

Comment: try vertical-align in div not Menu.

Comment: I tried that it did not work:(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Using this CSS for button

```
.ButtonClass
{
 border: thin groove #000000;
 vertical-align: bottom;
 }
```

And if you are looking for alignment inside div.You can use `position:absolute;` to absolutely position an element within a parent div. 
When using `position:absolute;` the element will be positioned absolutely from the first positioned parent div, if it can't find one it will position absolutely from the window so you will need to make sure the content div is positioned relatively.

So add `position:relative;` to the content div, remove the float from the button and add the following css:

```
position: absolute;
right:    0;
bottom:   0;
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, gonna read up on the position attribute! thanks!

Comment: I found a slight problem here. When i add several buttons they get stacked on eachother. I tried solving this by setting the margin at 0 5px but it doesn´t seem to work

Answer (score 1):

Vertical align will work only for table cells<sup>1</sup>:

```
.Menu
{
    display: table-cell;
}
```

<sup>1</sup> Actually it will also work for inline blocks, but with different effect.

Comment: How do i align the buttons in a div then?

Comment: Thanks this worked aswell! i accepted the other answer since im trying to avoid using anything that has to do with tables.